# simple Api for resizing image using typescript and sharp

Tags: node.js, typescript, sharp

I'm making an API that takes an image from the database by getting it using the URL like this (http://localhost:3000/city/?name=encenadaport&width=200&height=200)
I made the code and the function that handle the resizing issue the problem is when I write the URL it gives me
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\Programming\Udacity_FWD\Projects\Image_Api\assets\thumbnail\santamonica_300_200.png'
and when I rerun it works
I think it sends a response before it creates the resized image what shall I do
this is the part that handles the resizing

```
enter code here

  imgResize(imageLoc, name as string, width, height, newLocation);

  res.sendFile(`${newLocation}/${name}_${width}_${height}.png`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making imgResize `async` function. Then `await` imgResize before calling `res.sendFile`. I am guessing that `res.sendFile` is being called before `imgResize` finishes processing.